# PHP Generate IP's list from ip range

Tags: php, networking, geolocation, ip, network-protocols

Here for example is one ISP assigned ip ranges.

```
91.105.0.0/17
46.109.0.0/16
194.8.16.0/21
194.8.24.0/22
194.8.40.0/23
194.8.43.0/24
195.122.0.0/19
195.13.128.0/17
80.232.128.0/17
81.198.0.0/16
84.237.128.0/17
87.110.0.0/16
194.8.9.0/24
194.8.12.0/23
195.114.32.0/19
195.2.96.0/19
62.85.0.0/17
87.246.144.0/20
87.246.160.0/19
78.84.0.0/16
193.200.224.0/24
95.68.0.0/17
```

if i am correct, for this range 193.200.224.0/24 there is ip's 
    from
    193.200.224.1
    to 
    193.200.224.255

and 87.110.0.0/16
     from
     87.110.1.1
     to 
     87.110.255.255

But how about 0/17, 0/19, how to calculate those?

**I need help to write php function to generate automatically all ip's**

I will put all ranges to database then run php script and generate ip list for each range.

Purpose off all this? i want my countries all ip adreses, so i can analyse my website visitors even more.

thanx

Comment: You should take a look at some of the comments on the ip2long man page, many of them deal with cases similar to yours, and none of them require generating complete tables of ip's -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 193.200.224.0/24, ip addresses are in range from 193.200.224.0 to 193.200.224.255. That is the range of 256 ip addresses - 2^(32-24) = 2^8 = 256

For 91.105.0.0/17 it's the same calculation - 2^(32-17) = 2 ^ 15 = 32768 ip adresses starting from 91.105.0.0.

You can use some kind of nested loops to generate all ip addresses in range.

Comment: what is number 32? in 2^(32-17)??

Comment: ip address is a 32-bit number

Answer (score 10):

This is what i came up with:

```
$range  = "194.8.42.0/24";
function ipListFromRange($range){
    $parts = explode('/',$range);
    $exponent = 32-$parts[1].'-';
    $count = pow(2,$exponent);
    $start = ip2long($parts[0]);
    $end = $start+$count;
    return array_map('long2ip', range($start, $end) );
}
```

return array with all ip addreses
in  my case i used this to get 2 million ip addreses from 180 isp's.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some sort of on-line calculator, e.g.
http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/SubnetCalculator.jsp?ipAddress=91.105.0.0&cidr=17

There you can see addresses and masks in binary code. You should take first address and XOR it with mask. The first digits (left 17 on the /17 masks) are common for all adresses on the subnet (these are 1 on the mask), last ones (0 on the mask) are "free to use" in the subnet.